# Iterate through JSON from MapQuest API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mapquest

I'm parsing JSON response from the MapQuest API. I need all of the 'narratives' from the 'legs' node under 'maneuvers' (legs-> maneuvers -> get all narratives), but I cannot figure it out.

I can get most of the values like so:

```
$(function(){
   var mq = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonResponse);
   $("#fuel").html(mq.renderMatrixResults[0].route.fuelUsed);
   $("#rtime").html(mq.renderMatrixResults[0].route.realTime);
});
```

Part of JSON response:

```
{
    "renderMatrixResults": [
        {
            "route": {
                "hasTollRoad": true,
                "computedWaypoints": [

                ],
                "fuelUsed": 2.24,
                "hasUnpaved": false,
                "hasHighway": true,
                "realTime": 5556,
                "boundingBox": {
                    "ul": {
                        "lng": -74.240074,
                        "lat": 40.662548
                    },
                    "lr": {
                        "lng": -74.132072,
                        "lat": 40.573451
                    }
                },
                "distance": 38.998,
                "time": 5523,
                "hasSeasonalClosure": false,
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "latLng": {
                            "lng": -74.18862,
                            "lat": 40.609712
                        },
                        "adminArea4": "Brooklyn",
                        "adminArea5Type": "City",
                        "adminArea4Type": "County",
                        "adminArea5": "Brooklyn",
                        "street": "1234 Test Lane",
                        "adminArea1": "US",
                        "adminArea3": "NY",
                        "type": "s",
                        "displayLatLng": {
                            "lng": -74.188621,
                            "lat": 40.60971
                        },
                        "linkId": 33589148,
                        "postalCode": "10001-6992",
                        "sideOfStreet": "L",
                        "dragPoint": false,
                        "adminArea1Type": "Country",
                        "geocodeQuality": "POINT",
                        "geocodeQualityCode": "P1AAA",
                        "adminArea3Type": "State"
                    },
                    {
                        "latLng": {
                            "lng": -74.194858,
                            "lat": 40.601623
                        },
                        "adminArea4": "Brooklyn",
                        "adminArea5Type": "City",
                        "adminArea4Type": "County",
                        "adminArea5": "Brooklyn",
                        "street": "5678 Example Street",
                        "adminArea1": "US",
                        "adminArea3": "NY",
                        "type": "s",
                        "displayLatLng": {
                            "lng": -74.194854,
                            "lat": 40.601623
                        },
                        "linkId": 33361764,
                        "postalCode": "10001-5483",
                        "sideOfStreet": "R",
                        "dragPoint": false,
                        "adminArea1Type": "Country",
                        "geocodeQuality": "POINT",
                        "geocodeQualityCode": "P1AAA",
                        "adminArea3Type": "State"
                    }
                ],
                "hasCountryCross": false,
                "legs": [
                    {
                        "hasTollRoad": false,
                        "index": 0,
                        "roadGradeStrategy": [
                            [

                            ]
                        ],
                        "hasHighway": false,
                        "hasUnpaved": false,
                        "distance": 0.882,
                        "time": 145,
                        "origIndex": 1,
                        "hasSeasonalClosure": false,
                        "origNarrative": "Go west on some road",
                        "hasCountryCross": false,
                        "formattedTime": "00:02:25",
                        "destNarrative": "Proceed to 789 GIRAFFE STREET",
                        "destIndex": 1,
                        "maneuvers": [
                            {
                                "signs": [

                                ],
                                "index": 0,
                                "maneuverNotes": [

                                ],
                                "direction": 4,
                                "narrative": "Start out going south on Elephant Avenue.",
                                "iconUrl": "https://content.mapquest.com/mqsite/turnsigns/icon-dirs-start_sm.gif",
                                "distance": 0.57,
                                "time": 79,
                                "linkIds": [

                                ],
                                "streets": [
                                    "Elephant Avenue"
                                ],
                                "attributes": 0,
                                "transportMode": "AUTO",
                                "formattedTime": "00:01:19",
                                "directionName": "South",
                                "mapUrl": "https://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd|luur20uanq,b0=o5-9ayxdw&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,40.60971,-74.188621,0,0|purple-2,40.602351999999996,-74.189582,0,0|ï¿½er=40.606031,-74.18910149999999&zoom=10&rand=-1416511403&session=53c1fb45-030d-0004-02b7-16b5-00163e4c0d3f",
                                "startPoint": {
                                    "lng": -74.188621,
                                    "lat": 40.60971
                                },
                                "turnType": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "signs": [

                                ],
                                "index": 1,
                                "maneuverNotes": [

                                ],
                                "direction": 7,
                                "narrative": "Turn right onto Tiger Blvd.",
                                "iconUrl": "https://content.mapquest.com/mqsite/turnsigns/rs_right_sm.gif",
                                "distance": 0.269,
                                "time": 56,
                                "linkIds": [

                                ],
                                "streets": [
                                    "Tiger Blvd"
                                ],
                                "attributes": 0,
                                "transportMode": "AUTO",
                                "formattedTime": "00:00:56",
                                "directionName": "West",
                                "mapUrl": "https://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd|luur20uanq,b0=o5-9ayxdw&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-2,40.602351999999996,-74.189582,0,0|purple-3,40.601127,-74.194366,0,0|ï¿½er=40.601739499999994,-74.191974&zoom=12&rand=-1416511403&session=53c1fb45-030d-0004-02b7-16b5-00163e4c0d3f",
                                "startPoint": {
                                    "lng": -74.189582,
                                    "lat": 40.602352
                                },
                                "turnType": 2
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but here is the idea. You can use a function that will traverse object tree and collect items specified by a path.

```
function getPath(path, obj) {
     var name, value;
     path = path instanceof Array ? path: path.split('.'); //convert path to array
     name = path.shift(); //get the first name
     value = obj[name]; //extract value
     if(!path.length || value == null) { //last name or value is null or undefined
         return value;
     }
     if(value instanceof Array) { //if value is array - concat
         return [].concat.apply([], value.map(function(item){ 
                                 return getPath(path.slice(0), item);
                              }));
     } 
     return getPath(path, value); //else go deeper
}
```

Usage:

```
var narratives 
     = getPath('renderMatrixResults.route.legs.maneuvers.narrative', mq);
```

I believe the path is correct.

Comment: Figured it out, I need to do an outer and inner loop to iterate through the json response to collect all of the directions, but your solution at least got me the first set of directions

Comment: @Patriotec Cool. Just wonder what my function actually returns for your data?